# Is class_exists case sensitive?

Tags: php

According to PHP's documentation [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) is not case sensitive. However, I'm experiencing that it is. For example, `class_exists("\\My\\Foo")` returns true but `class_exists("\\My\\foo")` returns false.

I'm running PHP 5.3.3. I have two separate environments. This is working correctly in one environment, but the other environment is acting like it cares about case.

What am I missing? Is there a config setting somewhere?

Comment: Which system? Have you an autoload? This could be normal on a Unix system (files are case sensitive) with an autoload (class is not yet known to php until it tries to load it).

Comment: This example is not well written. You cannot have a class named class.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://eval.in/13037. Please update your question with any information that better clarifies your problem.

Comment: I just used "Class" as an example, sorry, pretend I used "Foo" for the class name. If it's pertinent the actual class name is "Link". The environment that this is working on is:
Darwin 12.2.1 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.1: root:xnu 2050.20.9~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

The environment that is showing case sensitivity is:
Linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

There is an autoload mechanism but it's handled via Symfony 2.0.9. The codebase and autoloaders are the same on both systems.

Comment: I find this question fairly well written, and it instantly solved my problem. My only complaints are when you say "two separate environments" would have been good to name them (Just add "Mac OS works, Linux doesn't") and that the answer has been edited into the question, rather than posted as a self answer. The "I sincerely apologize" bit is just unnecessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you comparing windows/mac to linux?

Assume the file `Wooby\Dooby\Foo.php` exists. With the following contents:

```
<?php
namespace Wooby\Dooby;

class Foo {}
```

### Class names are not case sensitive

If a class already exists, it doesn't matter what case you use to refer to it, the class will be found:

```
<?php

require "Wooby/Dooby/Foo.php";

echo "Class Wooby\\Dooby\\foo does " . (class_exists("Wooby\\Dooby\\foo") ? '' : "NOT") . " exist\n";
echo "Class wooby\\dooby\\foo does " . (class_exists("wooby\\dooby\\foo") ? '' : "NOT") . " exist\n";
echo "Class Wooby\\Dooby\\Foo does " . (class_exists("Wooby\\Dooby\\Foo") ? '' : "NOT") . " exist\n";
```

Running the above test file would return:

```
-> php index.php 
Class Wooby\Dooby\foo does  exist
Class wooby\dooby\foo does  exist
Class Wooby\Dooby\Foo does  exist
```

### Filesystems are case sensitive

If a class does *not* exist and you use an autoloader - then case does matter. Consider the above example modified to use a simple autoloader:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

function __autoload($name) {
    $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $name) '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include $file;
    }
}

echo "Class Wooby\\Dooby\\foo does " . (class_exists("Wooby\\Dooby\\foo") ? '' : "NOT") . " exist\n";
echo "Class wooby\\dooby\\foo does " . (class_exists("wooby\\dooby\\foo") ? '' : "NOT") . " exist\n";
echo "Class Wooby\\Dooby\\Foo does " . (class_exists("Wooby\\Dooby\\Foo") ? '' : "NOT") . " exist\n";
```

The results would be:

```
-> php index.php 
Class Wooby\Dooby\foo does NOT exist
Class wooby\dooby\foo does NOT exist
Class Wooby\Dooby\Foo does  exist
```

Because the autoloader is looking for paths which match the missing classname, only the last entry triggers including a file and loading the class.

*Unless* you're using windows or a mac<sup>1</sup> which both use case-insensitive file systems.

### Summary

Class names in php are not case-sensitive, but your code likely is as it effectively inherits the case-sensitivity of the file-system. Obviously it's best to use consistent case and not rely on php correcting lazy development habits.

Note that [class_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) has a parameter to turn on or off (on by default) the use of an autoloader when looking for none-existent classes.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> More accurately HFS is, by default, case-insensitive but case-preserving.

Comment: This ended up being the issue buried in an autoloader that I had mistakenly thought was case insensitive. Thank you.