# What could be the reason for a Zend Application to works on one machine but not the other?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, centos, zend-server

I have a ZF2 application that is functional on several machines. All running Zend Server. It has been very difficult to hunt down the problem so please ask questions to help get closer to the issue.

The Machines running the application are :

- Zend Server on Osx El Capitan.
- Zend Server on Centos 7 using virtual box
- Zend Server on Centos 6.

The machine that shows the problem is running:

- Zend Server on Centos 6 using Virtual box.

A use statement like this

`use Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl\Column\DateTime;`

Would throw an error on the problematic machine but not on the working machines. That is because the actual class name is `Datetime` and not `DateTime`. So changing the `T` to `t` gets rid of the error.

Is there certain php configuration I am missing and that is why i have this error? or is it zend server or operating system issue?

php -v
PHP 7.0.11

zend server version 9.0.1

Another error I get :

> While attempting to create apiv1modulenamecontroller(alias: Api\V1\ModuleName\Controller) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.

note the lowerCase in `apiv1modulenamecontroller`

Comment: What are the versions of PHP on each Instance?

Comment: I thought all unix system were case sensitive

Comment: Its just the way the Linux operating system is designed. I recommended to always create your code for case-sensitive file systems.

Comment: @lemoney each instance has php 7.* . a couple have 7.0 and one has 7.1

Comment: @CodeGodie that could be posted as an answer. Then the question can be closed and you would get an upvote...

Comment: @CodeGodie so the issue is the operating system i am deploying to? If so what can I do to move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens by design. It is just the way the Linux operating system is designed. As a rule of thumb, it is recommended to always create your code for case-sensitive file systems so that your code is ready if ever you deploy your code to a server that follows this strictly.

Comment: @Wilt can you suggest a solution to move on? I am still using the same operating system as other working machine, it is not like i am using IIS or a different stack!

Comment: I think what you are suggesting, someone explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488632/php-class-exists-acting-case-sensitive)

Comment: @mehany I suggest you stick to the casing as used inside the class names. If you use upper and lower casing exactly the way it was used in original variable/class names you should never have such problems again.